# ROS Answers SE migration: EKF Odom tf

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I need to change the tf link from Odom to base_footprint to Odom->"Turtlebot/base_footprint. I've read some other forums but I'm still stuck. I've tried to change the launch file paramaters but this hasn't effected the base_footprint destination.

Thanks,

I'm on Ros electric

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52751/ekf-odom-tf/) by [imageryeel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3979/imageryeel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
nh_private.param("output_frame", output_frame_, std::string("odom_combined"));
nh_private.param("sensor_timeout", timeout_, 1.0);
nh_private.param("odom_used", odom_used_, true);
nh_private.param("imu_used",  imu_used_, true);
nh_private.param("vo_used",   vo_used_, true);
nh_private.param("debug",   debug_, false);
nh_private.param("self_diagnose",  self_diagnose_, false);
double freq;
nh_private.param("freq", freq, 30.0);
```

These are the parameters that you can change ( code is from odom_estimation_node.cpp
in the source directory of robot_pose_ekf )

Seems like you can not change base frame id as a parameter. You can change it manually and recompile the source. I am not very sure if you can remap tf frames but I checked [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/9149/remapping-tf-frames/), it is not possible right now i guess

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0